# Commands through an interface like Command Prompt

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering is there a way to run an input form a user as a command without using switch or if statements?

For example if I had a form that contained a 10 by 10 picture frame, and wanted to change its size to 100 by 100. Better yet, is there a way to use a `string` that is defined in code:
`string newString = "";` 
then change the name of said string: `newString = "newButton" + count;`

This code would be used like so:

```
   for (int count = 0; count < records) // Records being the count of records to   be presented.
          { 
            newString = "newButton" + count;
            Button newString.ToString() = new Button();
          } //Uses the newString to give      ID name to the new buttons.
```

Some thing similar to this would be using java code to create a table for a servlet using the `<tag>` and the `out_print` command.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you are trying to create controls dynamically you should look at reflection. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like maybe you're looking for a `Dictionary<T,T>`.  You could implement your loop idea like this:

```
var buttons = new Dictionary<string,Button>();
for (int count = 0; count < records)
{ 
    newString = "newButton" + count; 
    var newButton = new Button();
    buttons.Add(newString, newButton);
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm that may actually work, I would need to try this, thanks :D

Comment: OK I am unsure that would work because I'm looking for the newString that is created to become the ID of the button, e.g. if I have count1 as the string I want the button id to be count1, so: `Button count1 = new Button();` etc.

Comment: @VasaSerafin so why not just set `newButton.ID = newString`?

Comment: Yea I had just told myself off for not doing that... just had to add: `Button newButton = new Button();` 
`newButton.Name = newString;`